# Different ways of defining a curvature in 2 dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

[image]

This is an exercise about defining curvatures. I cannot exactly understand what it means by (b) and (c). What exactly means by "approximation"? And what are the relations between (a), (b) and (c)? Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

When two curves meet, we can define the [**order of contact**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(mathematics)):

- Zeroth-order contact if the curves have a simple crossing (not tangent).
- First-order contact if the two curves are tangent.
- Second-order contact if the curvatures of the curves are equal. Such curves are said to be osculating.

> According to *Margaret Gow*'s [**book**](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=8DL9vYsWvDcC&lpg=PA510&ots=pZgFResgG_&dq=curvature%20margaret%20Gow%20pure%20mathematics&hl=zh-TW&pg=PA499#v=onepage&q&f=false).
>
> The reciprocal of the curvature at any point $P$ on a curve is called the *radius of curvature* at $P$ and is denoted by $\rho$.  Hence
>
> $$\rho=\frac{1}{\kappa}$$
>
> The term radius of curvature is used because $\rho$ is the radius of the circle whose curvature is the same as that of the given curve at $P$.

With the unit normal vector at the given point, we can draw the [**osculating circle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) and so on.

- For circle $X^2+(Y-A)^2=A^2$, $$R_c=A$$
- For parabola $Y=\dfrac{X^2}{B}$,
  \begin{align}
    \kappa &= \frac{Y''}{(1+Y'^{2})^{3/2}} \\
    &= \frac{\dfrac{2}{B}}
            {\left( 1+\dfrac{4X^2}{B^2} \right)^{3/2}}
  \end{align}

  Put $(X,Y)=(0,0)$,
  \begin{align}
    \frac{1}{R_c} &= \frac{2}{B} \\
    R_c &= \frac{B}{2}
  \end{align}

See more on physical aspects [**here**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379471/expression-for-the-centripetal-acceleration/379520#379520).